# Format like KSQL long timestamp in ABAP?

Tags: timestamp, apache-kafka-streams, abap, date-formatting, ksqldb

How to create an KSQL Timestamp in ABAP ?

ISO Extended is not enough.

"timestamp":"2022-02-07T08:35:02,4595190",

I need this ..

"timestamp": "2021-03-23T14:00:04.893888792Z",

Who has an idea ?

Comment: What's `ABAP` ?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt ABAP is the proprietary programming language of SAP NetWeaver systems. Check the tag info for more information.

Comment: In what format do you have the timestamp in your ABAP program? TIMESTAMP? TIMESTAMPL? Or a pair of TYPE d and TYPE t variables? Or would any of those do because you just want to get the current datetime?

Answer (score 2):

Use TIMESTAMPL data type. "2021-03-23T14:00:04.893888792Z" is just external presentation. It's 20210323140004.893888792 inside

Example:

```
DATA lv_now TYPE timestampl.

GET TIME STAMP FIELD lv_now.

DATA(lv_str) = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize(
    data             = lv_now
*    compress         = compress
*    name             = name
*    pretty_name      = pretty_name
*    type_descr       = type_descr
*    assoc_arrays     = assoc_arrays
    ts_as_iso8601    = abap_true
*    expand_includes  = expand_includes
*    assoc_arrays_opt = assoc_arrays_opt
*    numc_as_string   = numc_as_string
*    name_mappings    = name_mappings
).

WRITE lv_str.
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that converts an SAP Long timestamp TIMESTAMPL into JSON and Produces "2021-03-23T14:00:04.893888792Z"   .  With the "Z "  zulu for UTC timezone . That I would like to see.
On our 7.5 Kernel I get this {"TIMESTAMPL":20220207171054.259076}

Comment: Use /UI2/CL_JSON class

Comment: @alezhu Can you add an example for how to do this with this class to your answer?

Comment: ok there is an option in the class  /UI2/CL_JSON to use iso 8061 settings.
So useful if speed is of no concern. Unfortunately the class is too slow for us.
But the option could be useful for the pfeffer

Answer (score 1):

> "timestamp":"2022-02-07T08:35:02,4595190"

I assume that is a typo. Looks like json output and  The SAP Standard JSON conversion of TZNTSTMPL uses decimal point.

You may also have fun dealing with time fields and initial dates.
I had to write converters to handle the output.

If you are using the identity transformation approach,
something like this,

```
   " get a JSON writer
    lo_writer = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( 
                  type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json
                  no_empty_elements  = i_suppress_initial ).

    CALL TRANSFORMATION id  SOURCE json_root_node = myAbapStru
                            RESULT XML lo_writer

    l_xstring  = lo_writer->get_output( ).

   lo_converter   = cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>create(  
                          input = l_xstring
                          encoding = 'UTF-8'  ).


    lo_converter->read( EXPORTING   n    = lv_length
                       IMPORTING    data = r_string ).
```

Then you get the output in SAPs interpretation of JSON Standard.
Which is unfortunately valid in ISO8601.   Since ALL timestamps in sap are in UTC the Z can be dropped :(

You may need to parse/fix the resulting JSON string before sending it.
I ended up fixing the result at the other end.
[In c# using NetwonSoft Datatype converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm)

EDIT: for class /UI2/CL_JSON.
using the old ABAP parser, there is an option to do this as user @ALEZHU points out.

```
data: begin of test,
      ts type timestampl,
      END OF test,
      l_json type string.
get time STAMP FIELD test-ts.


l_json = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( EXPORTING data             = test
                                   ts_as_iso8601    = 'X' ).
write: /  l_json.
```

produces: **{"TS":"2022-02-10T06:27:13.8734110Z"}**